# final JPanel with added labels (java)

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, final, flowlayout

Iam trying to position my jlabel in a jpanel what is made final because of an actionlistener.

```
final JPanel panelPayDetails = new JPanel();
panelPayDetails.setBounds(250, 25, 350, 250);

JLabel lblnumber = new JLabel("Insert Number:");         
lblnumber.setFont(Applicatie.FONT_12_BOLD);
lblnumber.setBounds(5, 5, 200, 20);

panelPayDetails.add(lblnumber);
panelPayDetails.setVisible(false);
jpExtraDetails.add(panelPayDetails);

bill.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {                
              if(bill.getSelectedItem() == "CREDIT CARD")
              {

                   panelPayDetails.setVisible(true);
              }
            }
        });
```

im not luck so far.. because the label is positioned in the middle of the jpanel.. how come?

Comment: Your problem isn't related to `final`. Can you remove the tag, and if you have time remove reference from it in your question up top? Also, can you add a tag for swing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the default layout manager for JPanel is FlowLayout, which centers things. [Read this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html).

Comment: (By default, FlowLayout can be setup to align to the right and left)

Comment: te weird thing is, i can positiom my labels when the panel is not final :/